# UI automation seems to run in background without launching browser

Tags: user-interface, jenkins, automation, ranorex

I'm trying to setup Jenkins to execute our UI automation(Ranorex) tests.  When the job runs, the IE browser does NOT launch, thus the tests don't run.

Is there some setting that I'm missing here?

The UI automation code is built into a .exe, which is called from a .bat file.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you're running Jenkins as a service, make sure desktop interaction is enabled for that service.

Comment: I finally figure this out.  Now I'm having other problems with the automation tool.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already read the blog [Integrating Ranorex Automation in Jenkins CI Process](http://www.ranorex.com/blog/integrating-ranorex-automation-in-jenkins-continuous-integration-process) on the Ranorex website?

Comment: yes - I have read the blog and followed all steps.  I thought the solution of running Jenkins via the command line would have fixed it, but still not running the browser.